# Cisco 4221 basic internet setup

Tags: cisco-isr

I've just got a new cisco 4221 isr router that has sd-wan  firmware. This is my first experience with this series and im trying to set ip up for basic internet access but no luck.

Here is an overview of my Lab:

PC ========> | Router | ==========> INTERNET

pc's ip : **172.16.10.1 / 24**

router's lan interface ip : **172.16.10.254 / 24**

router's wan interface public ip: **x.x.101.195 / 29**

gateway: **x.x.101.193**

I am able to ping websites from the cli and everything seems ok . However I don't have internet connectivity from my pc . I can however reach my dns server for name resolution . Can anyone please tell me what im doing wrong ?

Here is the running config :

```
Building configuration...
!
! Last configuration change at 09:42:15 UTC Tue Oct 13 2020 by   NETCONF
!
version 16.9
no service pad
service timestamps debug datetime msec
service timestamps log datetime msec
service password-encryption
platform qfp utilization monitor load 80
no platform punt-keepalive disable-kernel-core
!
hostname Router
!
boot-start-marker
boot-end-marker


logging buffered 262144
no logging rate-limit
enable secret 5 $1$Xtl7h4NuUM5.
!
aaa new-model
!
!
aaa authentication login default local
aaa authorization exec default local
!
aaa session-id common
fhrp version vrrp v3

ip name-server 192.168.20.173
no ip dhcp use class


no ip igmp ssm-map query dns

subscriber templating

ipv6 unicast-routing

multilink bundle-name authenticated

license udi pid ISR4221/K9 sn FGL232030R8
no license smart enable
license smart transport callhome
diagnostic bootup level minimal

spanning-tree mode rapid-pvst
spanning-tree extend system-id

netconf-yang

username sysadmin privilege 15 secret 5 wxyz

redundancy
mode none

no crypto ikev2 diagnose error

interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
  ip address x.x.101.195 255.255.255.248
  ip nat outside
  negotiation auto
  no cdp enable

interface GigabitEthernet0/0/1
  ip address 172.16.10.254 255.255.255.0
  ip nat inside
  negotiation auto

ip forward-protocol nd
no ip http server
no ip http secure-server
ip dns server
no ip nat service skinny tcp port 2000
no ip nat service sip tcp port 5060
no ip nat service sip udp port 5060
no ip nat service H225
no ip nat service ras
no ip nat service rtsp udp
no ip nat service rtsp tcp
no ip nat service dns tcp
no ip nat service dns udp
no ip nat service netbios-ns tcp
no ip nat service netbios-ns udp
no ip nat service netbios-ssn
no ip nat service netbios-dgm
no ip nat service ldap
no ip nat service sunrpc udp
no ip nat service sunrpc tcp
no ip nat service msrpc tcp
no ip nat service tftp
no ip nat service rcmd
no ip nat service pptp
no ip nat service ftp
no ip nat service gatekeeper
no ip nat service dns-reset-ttl
ip nat inside source list 101 interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0  overload
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 x.x.101.193
no ip rsvp signalling rate-limit

ip ssh version 2
ip scp server enable
!
access-list 101 permit ip any any
no ipv6 mld ssm-map query dns

control-plane

mgcp behavior rsip-range tgcp-only
mgcp behavior comedia-role none
mgcp behavior comedia-check-media-src disable
mgcp behavior comedia-sdp-force disable
!
mgcp profile default

line con 0
transport input none
stopbits 1
line vty 0 4
  transport input ssh
line vty 5 80
  transport input ssh
!
 wsma agent exec
!
 wsma agent config
!
 wsma agent filesys
!
 wsma agent notify
!
!

telemetry ietf subscription 2147483605
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:bridge-interface-state-  change
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483606
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:bridge-state-change
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483607
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:utd-update
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483608
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:utd-ips-alert
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483609
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:cellular-network-status- change
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483610
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:cellular-modem-status-change
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483611
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:cellular-sim-status-change
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483612
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:app-dpi-flows-out-of-memory
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483613
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:aaa-admin-pwd-change
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483614
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:system-aaa-login-fail
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483615
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:system-logout-change
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483616
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:system-login-change
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483617
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:fib-updates
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483618
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:cpu-usage
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483619
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:memory-usage
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483620
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:ospf-interface-state-change
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483621
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:disk-usage
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483622
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:system-reboot-issued
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483623
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:vrrp-group-state-change
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483624
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:usb-state-change
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483625
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:sfp-support-state
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483626
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:sfp-state-change
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483627
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:pim-state-change
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483628
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:pim-fault
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483629
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:pem-state-change
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483630
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:pem-fault
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483631
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:fantray-fault
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483632
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:fan-fault
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483633
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:tempsensor-state
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483634
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:tempsensor-fault
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483635
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:sdcard-fault
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483636
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:emmc-fault
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277
telemetry ietf subscription 2147483637
encoding encode-xml
filter xpath /ios-events-ios-xe-oper:flash-fault
receiver ip address 0.0.0.0 0 protocol rfc5277
stream rfc5277

end
```

Comment: Gateway on the PC incorrect? I don't see anything in the config that would prevent outside access.

Comment: These are my PC's network settings 

ip : 172.16.10.1
mask : 255.255.255.0
gateway : 172.16.10.254
Can't really find out what is restricting my pc from internet access

Comment: Possibly all the turned off NAT ALGs. There's really no reason to have all those *no ip nat service* lines.